# JPanel visibility (true) not showing

Tags: java

I got a mainframe and a strartscreen with a timer counting down from 3, 2, 1.
I've set the mainframe main.setVisible(false) but when the timer reaches 0 I want it to be main.setVisible(true). I did this but it doesnt seem to work and I dont know what I am doing wrong. This is what I have so far:
*Mainframe:

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

public JLabel welkom, vraag, vraagnr, minimize, close;
public JButton btnVolgende, btnExit, btnVraag;
public ImageIcon icon;

public MainPanel() {
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(false); // visibility false
```

Timerframe:

```
MainPanel main = new MainPanel();
    Vraag1 vraag1 = new Vraag1();


    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() 
    {
        int seconden = 3;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            seconden--;
            if(seconden > 0)
            {
                countdown.setText("" + seconden);
            }
            else if(seconden == 0)
            {
                main.setVisible(true); //setframe visible
                vraag1.setVisible(true);
                setVisible(false);
            }
        }

    };
    afteller = new Timer(1000, listener);
    afteller.start();

}
```

And here is my JFrame:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.sun.glass.events.MouseEvent;

public class Frame {

    static JFrame frame;
    static MainPanel paneel;
    static Vraag1 vraag1;
    static StartScherm start;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setTitle("Voetbal quiz - Edward Kerckhof");
        frame.setSize(1191,677);    
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("src/images/voetbal.PNG");
        frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());

        vraag1 = new Vraag1();
        vraag1.setBounds(0,0,1191,677);
        frame.add(vraag1);

        paneel = new MainPanel();
        paneel.setBounds(0,0,1191,677);
        frame.add(paneel);     

        start = new StartScherm();
        start.setBounds(0,0,1191,677);
        frame.add(start);

        frame.setVisible(true); 

        }       
}
```

Comment: mainpanel should extends JFrame not JPanel

Comment: Why not also instantiate your `JFrame` inside the `else if` block where you need it to be visible? Unless it's doing some logic from the beginning of the program...

Comment: I'm sorry I formulated my question wrong. The "MainPanel' is not my mainframe but just the welcome Panel. I have another class which is my acutal main frame. The one showed here is in fact a panel.

Comment: @Edward Kerckhor Did you use a `JFrame` in any part of your code?

Comment: If you use a JFrame, you should show your code for that as well. Many problems could be caused by the `JFrame` code.

Comment: @user3437460 here's my JFrame: https://gyazo.com/f654cec93f0fa2b9f041dd3c88c77f26